# MongoDB: How access a copied database with different machines?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

What I 'm trying to archive is save a mongoDB  database in a external HD, for instance, and then use it in all my machines. Just it. How can I do that?

My first attempt was trying to access a database using my Mac (64-bit) . This database was created in another computer (Windows XP 32-Bit) and I just copied and pasted it to a local file. After that, I started a mongod process.

Then, when I tried to find a document into the db, the following error incurred:

```
***** SERVER RESTARTED *****


Fri Jun  6 00:21:28.250 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4158 port=27017 dbpath=/Users/ucaiado/Desktop/MONGODB 64-bit host=Uira-Caiado-Castros-iMac.local
Fri Jun  6 00:21:28.250 [initandlisten] 
Fri Jun  6 00:21:28.250 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Fri Jun  6 00:21:28.250 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.8
Fri Jun  6 00:21:28.250 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Fri Jun  6 00:21:28.250 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin Uira-Caiado-Castros-iMac.local 13.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Wed Apr  2 23:52:02 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.92.1~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Fri Jun  6 00:21:28.250 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Fri Jun  6 00:21:28.250 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/Users/ucaiado/Desktop/MONGODB", logappend: "true", logpath: "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log" }
Fri Jun  6 00:21:28.251 [initandlisten] journal dir=/Users/ucaiado/Desktop/MONGODB/journal
Fri Jun  6 00:21:28.251 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Fri Jun  6 00:21:28.253 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 16777216 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:28.336 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 16777216 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:28.349 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 33554432 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:28.537 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 16777216 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:28.550 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 33554432 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:28.697 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 16777216 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:28.717 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 33554432 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:28.996 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 16777216 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:29.036 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 33554432 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:29.691 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 16777216 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:29.723 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 33554432 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:29.810 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 16777216 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:29.831 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 33554432 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:29.903 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 16777216 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:29.903 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 33554432 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:30.091 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 16777216 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:30.091 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 33554432 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:30.175 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 16777216 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:30.179 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 33554432 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:30.235 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 16777216 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:30.241 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 33554432 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:30.291 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 16777216 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:30.300 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 33554432 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:30.332 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 16777216 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:30.340 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 33554432 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:30.381 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 16777216 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:30.384 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 33554432 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:30.428 [initandlisten] info openExisting file size 16777216 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:21:30.476 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Fri Jun  6 00:21:30.527 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Fri Jun  6 00:22:30.447 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: DBConnectionPool-cleaner took: 19ms
Fri Jun  6 00:22:30.639 [TTLMonitor] query local.system.indexes query: { expireAfterSeconds: { $exists: true } } ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:0 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:211363 nreturned:0 reslen:20 193ms
Fri Jun  6 00:25:19.285 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:62427 #1 (1 connection now open)
Fri Jun  6 00:25:25.465 [conn1] info openExisting file size 16777216 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:25:25.478 [conn1] info openExisting file size 33554432 but cmdLine.smallfiles=false
Fri Jun  6 00:25:25.818 [conn1] error: getFile() called in a read lock, yet file to return is not yet open
Fri Jun  6 00:25:25.818 [conn1]        getFile(1) _files.size:1 /Users/ucaiado/Desktop/MONGODB/prices.1
Fri Jun  6 00:25:25.818 [conn1]        context ns: prices.data
Fri Jun  6 00:25:25.864 [conn1]  prices.data Assertion failure false src/mongo/db/database.cpp 300
0x10609f8a9 0x106072a00 0x105d117a7 0x105bb380c 0x105d035b2 0x105d02238 0x105e34496 0x105e37074 0x105dd0c32 0x105bace7e 0x106091ba0 0x1060d7cf1 0x7fff89596899 0x7fff8959672a 0x7fff8959afc9 
 0   mongod                              0x000000010609f8a9 _ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo + 57
 1   mongod                              0x0000000106072a00 _ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j + 304
 2   mongod                              0x0000000105d117a7 _ZN5mongo8Database7getFileEiib + 1223
 3   mongod                              0x0000000105bb380c _ZN5mongo11DataFileMgr9getExtentERKNS_7DiskLocE + 60
 4   mongod                              0x0000000105d035b2 _ZNK5mongo7Forward4nextERKNS_7DiskLocE + 114
 5   mongod                              0x0000000105d02238 _ZN5mongo11BasicCursor7advanceEv + 72
 6   mongod                              0x0000000105e34496 _ZN5mongo23queryWithQueryOptimizerEiRKSsRKNS_7BSONObjERNS_5CurOpES4_S4_RKN5boost10shared_ptrINS_11ParsedQueryEEES4_RKNS_12ChunkVersionERNS7_10scoped_ptrINS_25PageFaultRetryableSectionEEERNSG_INS_19NoPageFaultsAllowedEEERNS_7MessageE + 1590
 7   mongod                              0x0000000105e37074 _ZN5mongo8runQueryERNS_7MessageERNS_12QueryMessageERNS_5CurOpES1_ + 4868
 8   mongod                              0x0000000105dd0c32 _ZN5mongo16assembleResponseERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE + 1154
 9   mongod                              0x0000000105bace7e _ZN5mongo16MyMessageHandler7processERNS_7MessageEPNS_21AbstractMessagingPortEPNS_9LastErrorE + 174
 10  mongod                              0x0000000106091ba0 _ZN5mongo17PortMessageServer17handleIncomingMsgEPv + 1056
 11  mongod                              0x00000001060d7cf1 _ZN5boost12_GLOBAL__N_112thread_proxyEPv + 177
 12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff89596899 _pthread_body + 138
 13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff8959672a _pthread_struct_init + 0
 14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff8959afc9 thread_start + 13
Fri Jun  6 00:25:26.408 [conn1] assertion 0 assertion src/mongo/db/database.cpp:300 ns:prices.data query:{ D: { $gte: new Date(1394236800000), $lt: new Date(1593561600000) } }
Fri Jun  6 00:25:26.408 [conn1] query prices.data query: { D: { $gte: new Date(1394236800000), $lt: new Date(1593561600000) } } ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 exception: assertion src/mongo/db/database.cpp:300 locks(micros) W:100556 r:890707 reslen:75 923ms
```

Comment: So your mongo db is on one machine and you want to store the data in some other disk, and you just assumed that it'll work just like that.   You can simply install the db on one machine and access it from other machines without copying to other machines, they just should be in networks, or may be i couldn't understand what you really really want

Comment: Yeh, it is exactly that. But if it should work, You could explain why it didn't work in this case? Copying the data to a local file? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential solution to your problem is to run `mongodump` and `mongorestore`

Run `mongodump` on the source machine. It will create a `dump` folder which you need to copy over to your destination.

On the destination, run `mongorestore` in the same location where you've copied the `dump` folder.

This will automatically import all data without copying over the system specific configuration.

Comment: Your hint to copy just the dump folder solved my problem. I had already tried to use the mongodump without success before, but I was trying to restore the data in the same folder where I copied the entire database.

As [Philip](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1620671/philipp) said, I guess that this procedure was appending the new 64-bit db to the older 32-bit db that caused a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that one system uses the 32bit version of MongoDB and the other the 64bit version. When you want to use the same database file on both, you should consistently use the 32bit version. The 32bit version has severe limitations (like not allowing more than 2GB of data), but for a development environment with limited data this might be adequate.

Comment: It makes sense and helped me to understand the issue. Thanks.